# Creating a superior JFrame over another

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two JFrames. Both are visible at same time.

One JFrame takes the whole screen..its just plain white. (it is acting as a background). And other JFrame is a small box with buttons/texts and other swing components.

The problem I get is when I click the big JFrame area, the JFrame box minimizes. So how do I specify java to make sure the JFrame box is always on top of the JFrame background?

Answer (score 4):

Use a [JInternalFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Answer (score 1):

Make the JFrame box a JPanel box.

Your application should only have one JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

JFrame is a TopLevel Component and therefore usually you don't put a JFrame into another. If you want to put your `smaller jframe` into your `bigger` I would subclass either JDialog or a JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

In general, an application should only have a single JFrame. Other windows should be dialogs.

> The problem I get is when I click the big JFrame area, the JFrame box minimizes.

When you use the dialog make sure you specify the frame as the owner of the dialog:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);
```

If the main frame is ever minimized, the dialog will also be minimized. When the frame is restored the dialog will always display on top of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

use Jdialog with setModal(false) for your small window ,

probably you want something similar to gimp 
look at gimp toolbox , only X at title , means its a Dialog.

hope that's help